# django generate a feed for a particular tag

Tags: django, tags, feed

I want to generate a feed of latest entries of a blog post under a particular tag. I used django-tagging. How can i do this? Here is how i defined my LatestEntriesFeed

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.utils.feedgenerator import Atom1Feed
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.contrib.syndication.feeds import Feed
from articles.models import Entry

current_site = Site.objects.get_current()

class LatestEntriesFeed(Feed):
    title = 'Latest Entries for %s' % current_site
    link = '/feeds/latest/'
    description = 'Latest entries posted.'

    def items(self):
        return Entry.live.all()[:100]

    def item_pubdate(self, item):
        return item.pub_date

    def item_guid(self, item):
        return "tag:%s,%s:%s" % (current_site.domain,
            item.pub_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
            item.get_absolute_url())
```

Answer (score 2):

After realizing how get_object() works i finally make it work. I added some imports:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from tagging.models import Tag, TaggedItem

class TagFeed(LatestEntriesFeed):

    def get_object(self, bits):
        if len(bits) != 1:
            raise ObjectDoesNotExist
        return Tag.objects.get(name__exact=bits[0])

    def title(self, obj):
        return "%s: Latest entries under the tag '%s'" % (current_site.name, obj.name)

    def description(self, obj):
        return "%s: Latest entries under the tag  '%s'" % (current_site.name, obj.name)

    def items(self, obj):
        return TaggedItem.objects.get_by_model(Entry, obj.name)
```

Lets say I access /feeds/tag/thetagnamehere/ then get_object will fetch tag object with name "thetagnamehere". Method items() will then fetch Entries under the tag "thetagnamehere". I also created feeds/tag_title.html and feeds/tag_description.html in my templates directory. In my project urls.py:

```
feeds = {
'latest': LatestEntriesFeed,
'tag': TagFeed,
}

(r'^feeds/(?P<url>.*)/$', 'django.contrib.syndication.views.feed',
    {'feed_dict': feeds}, ),
```

That's it. Im now able to generate a feed for a particular tag in my sidebar. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `items` method to the folowing:

```
from tagging.models import Tag, TaggedItem

def items(self):
    tag = Tag.objects.get(name='you tag name')
    return TaggedItem.objects.get_by_model(Entry, tag)
```

Comment: thanks alex that would be helpfull hint. im thinking of subclassing the LatestEntriesFeed.